# spring boot not recognizing application properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using `application-sqe.yml` and `application.yml` files where common properties are present in application.yml file and specific properties of `sqe env` present in `application-sqe.yml`.

After generating `war` file of My project and running the project can't able to access common properties file `application.yml` but project can able to access `application-sqe.yml`. As some of the common properties are present in `application.yml` project can't able to run the project with the error "properties are missing " please advice

Comment: You should explain more details for trying to help you. Could you share your project settings (is it a maven one?) ? Where do you store your properties file? etc ... Try to follow these guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Seem the file didn't make it into the war file. Did you look at the content of the war file to check?

Comment: After adding  annotation EnableAutoConfiguration and Component scan in main class project can able to access application.yml file .Thanks for reply

Comment: SpringBoot  need to run with `sqe` profile. Use the following command line argument to run : `java -jar  -Dspring.profiles.active=sqe app.jar`